# Order of Operations with ternary operator and OR operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, boolean-expression

Why is the order of operations from right to left in the first example?

This evaluates to World

```
"Hello" || true ? "World" : ""
```

This evaluates to Hello

```
"Hello" || (true ? "World" : "")
```

Comment: Operator Precedence https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table You can see OR is higher than Ternary. Not sure what you expect as an answer other than, that is the order.

Comment: @epascarello I wouldn't mind the Conditional and Logical OR operators having the same precedence. I wonder what the reason is for being at different levels

Comment: @MisterJojo The Conditional is an OR operation. Seems logical to have it at the same level as the Logical OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you know that operations are not executed from left to right, but following the operator priority: just think to:

```
1 + 2 * 3
```

do you expect `7` or `9`? As you experimented, ternary operator has the lower priority.

```
"Hello" || true ? "World" : ""
```

is equivalent to

```
("Hello" || true) ? "World" : ""
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. I expected them to be at the same level of precedence.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to logic precedence.

In the first example, the logic is used to determine whether "World" or "" is output. If either case `"Hello" || true` is true, the ternary operator will output "World".

In the second case, `||` is used as a fallback if short-circuit evaluation fails. That is, try to output the first value if it is true. If the first value, in this case "Hello" is false, then evaluate the next value (true ? "World" : "").

In both examples, the logic evaluates to true on the first value (Hello). The difference is that the first case is used as a ternary operator as a shortcut to using

```
if ("Hello" || true) {
    return "World"
} else {
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you.

```js
"Hello" || true ? "World" : ""; 

//is the same as:

if("Hello" || true) {
 console.log("World")
} else {
 console.log("");   
};              // Outputs World


console.log("Hello" || (true ? "World" : "")); //Outputs Hello

//sentence after OR is like:

if(true) {
 "World";
} else {
 "";
}
    
//For example:

console.log((true ? "World" : "") || "Hello"); //Outputs World

console.log("Hello" || (true ? "World" : "")); //Outputs Hello
```